# Iterable<Xxx>: Why can't you use [], you have to use new Array()

Tags: typescript, iterable

```
type XxxType = 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc'
interface Xxx {
    type: XxxType
}
interface MyXxx {
    name: string
    xxx: Xxx
}
interface MyObj {
    arr: Iterable<MyXxx>
}

const myObj: MyObj = {
    arr: [ { name: 'aaa', xxx: { type: 'aaa' } } ]
}

//emm....
Type '{ name: string; xxx: { type: string; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<MyXxx>'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'XxxType'. ts[2322]
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with what I wrote, but I'm not sure why I'm getting an error. and I don't get syntax hints.

---

When I changed the code from `[]` to `new Array`, no error was reported!

```
const myObj: MyObj = { arr: new Array({ name:'aa', xxx:{ type:'aaa'} }) }
```

Why???

Comment: This exact code doesn't generate any error in the playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgHnAKuaBeKByAhjjUA+mARiXoRgMZUYBQAlgHbAQBOAZlhdPHFAN40oQqKEgAuWAmSQaAX3pNWHLlACyIHv0HCGWALYQJAZ2AtGAc21CEcCTzkLm7TtHUB5IgCstwqFhYsEgCSTlhEADYQADzqPAB8DjQUAPYMJlB6IB6eEu5eUOgCvv6BUADa-FC6BhLYuAA0UDYSfCIotThYeLJQPQC6ckA. Could you create a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

```
tsconfig.json:
    "target": "es5" > "es2015"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).